# Why does my code repeat instead carry on when i input an integer?

Tags: python

> **it keeps repeating please help me**

```
new_custom = ""
while new_custom !=["y","n"]:
    new_custom = input("are you a new customer y/n \n").lower
    if new_custom == "y":
        if miles <= 5:
            print (7)
        else:
            print( 7 + ((miles - 5) * 2))
    elif new_custom == "n":
        if miles <= 5:
            print(8)
        else:
              print(8+((miles-5)*2))
```

i cant figure out why it keeps repeating

Comment: where is miles defined?

Comment: The `if` statement should come *after* the loop, not in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 errors present in your code:

```
new_custom !=["y","n"]
```

This does not check if a string is contained in the list; it checks to see if a list containing the same elements is present.

```
input("are you a new customer y/n \n").lower
```

By missing the brackets your script does not realise that lower is a function.

Using these 2 lines will correct your code:

```
while new_custom not in ["y","n"]:
    new_custom = input("are you a new customer y/n \n").lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

your while condition should be like this:

```
miles = 8
new_custom = ""
while new_custom not in ["y","n"]:
    new_custom = input("are you a new customer y/n \n").lower()
    if new_custom == "y":
        if miles <= 5:
            print (7)
        else:
            print( 7 + ((miles - 5) * 2))
    elif new_custom == "n":
        if miles <= 5:
            print(8)
        else:
              print(8+((miles-5)*2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the parentheses on your lower case check. Should be .lower() and the code should continue but the next error will be miles is not defined.